# How to use 2 multer middlewares in same post route

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to use 2 multer middleware in the same post route nodejs and reactjs stack. The first middleware is to store the file locally and the second one is to store it in the cloud.
An example of how I expect is:

```
router.post( "/upload", diskStorageUpload.array( 'files' ), cloudUpload.array( 'files' ) , upload);
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I get the following error.

> Error: Unexpected end of form
> at Multipart._final (D:\xarwin\xarwin-backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:588:17)
> at callFinal (internal/streams/writable.js:610:10)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Move two upload middlewares to a separate middleware where you'll handle uploads:

```
function multiUpload(req, res, next) {

    diskStorageUpload.array( 'files' )(req, res, next)
    cloudUpload.array( 'files' )(req, res, next);
    next();
}
```

and then use that middleware:

```
router.post( "/upload", multiUpload, upload);
```

Comment: My zip file becomes corrupt when I try doing this.

Comment: @SrivatsanNarasimhan hard to say... it shouldn't be related to this middleware, but rather to the content and your upload middlewares.. try using a singe upload: `router.post( "/upload", diskStorageUpload.array( 'files' ), upload)` and check if the file is still corrupt